# Will a kernel update overwrite my wireless driver from a newer kernel?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, updates

i run ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit Kernel Linux 3.2.0-59-generic but I installed the wireless driver from backports-3.13-rc2-1. Now all works well.

My question is about the kernel update because if I install the proposed security update to Linux 3.2.0-60-generic it overwrite the wireless driver I patched.

Is there a way to install the new kernel maintaining the wireless driver from backports-3.13-rc2-1??

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You compiled backports against your currently running kernel only. That means that when a later kernel version is installed by Update Manager, you must recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13-rc2-1  <-or wherever you downloaded the file
make clean
make defconfig-rtlwifi  <-or whatever suite you compiled
make
sudo make install
```

Another option is to simply install the 3.13 kernel from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13-trusty/ I suggest you get all the deb files appropriate to your architecture; either 32- or 64-bit; find out with:

```
arch
```

For instance, if yours is a 32-bit system (i686), then I suggest you download linux-image i386, linux-headers i386 and linux-headers all. Download them to your desktop and install with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: Hi, I solved enabling backports. Regards

Comment: I enabled the backports and installed the kernel 3.11 but the update manager still proposes to me the update of the kernel 3.2. How can I disable it?

Comment: sudo dpkg hold linux-image